# Pick a random element from a Hashtable

Tags: java

How do I generate a random `char` in java that is present in a hashtable?

For example, from the following table, I would like to choose either `X`, `O` or `I` randomly and put that value in `randomChar`.

```
char randomChar = 'O';

Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.put(1, 'X');
ht.put(10, 'O');
ht.put(12, 'I');
```

Comment: 1) Don't use raw types; 2) use `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`.

Comment: use array consisting of three values {1,10,12} and generate random number to find key to look up into Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no particular reason why you are using a `HashTable` to do this, then I suggest you just use an array instead. To get a random character you just generate a random number from `0` to `array.length - 1`:

```
char[] chars = { 'X', 'O', 'I' };
char randomChar = chars[new Random().nextInt(chars.length)];
```

However if you do want to use a `HashTable`, you should use a `HashMap` instead, and also you should not be using raw types:

```
Map<Integer, Character> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(1, 'X');
hashMap.put(10, 'O');
hashMap.put(12, 'I');
```

The first step to get a random `Character` is to get all of the `Character`s from the `HashMap`:

```
Collection<Character> characters = hashMap.values();
```

The `Collection` class however does not allow us to access the collection with an index so we need to construct a `List` from it:

```
List<Character> characterList = new ArrayList<>(characters);
```

Now to get a random character from this `List` you can generate a random number to use as an index. To do this you can use the `Random` class:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(hashMap.size());
```

Finally you get the random `Character` from the `List` using this index:

```
Character randomChar = characterList.get(randomIndex);
```

To do all of that in one line you can do:

```
Character randomChar = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.values()).get(new Random().nextInt(hashMap.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a `Hashtable` extract the key set with `keySet()` and take it as an array with `toArray`. Then take a random number in the range `0` -`size()-1`, pick the corresponding element from the array and extract the value associated in the table.

Or extract the values and pick one randomly with an equivalent procedure.